# How to extract specific file from partially downloaded zip file?

Tags: unzip

I have downloaded 82 GB dataset. When I tried to extract the original zip file, I got  partially downloaded zip files named test.zip.001, test.zip.002,....test.zip.007. I am unable to merge all these files from windows OS. Please guide me how to merge these files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your need.

### Label1: In case you want to extract data from those split zip files.

You don't need to merge them as one. Just put those `xxx.001, xxx.002 ...` fiels in the same folder, and then unzip the `xxx.001`, which will automatically concrete data in `xxx.002, xxx.003...` and unpack those data inside those zips, at least the `bandzip` software does.

### Label2: In case you just want a whole big 82GB zip file.

See the `Lebel1` to unzip them, and then create a new 82GB zip file from those extracted files.